# Converting cookie string into Python dict

Tags: python, dictionary, cookies, fiddler

In Fiddler, I captured an HTTPS request with the following cookie string sent from the client (visible in Inspectors > Raw):

```
Cookie: devicePixelRatio=1; ident=exists; __utma=13103r6942.2918; __utmc=13103656942; __utmz=13105942.1.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); mp_3cb27825a6612988r46d00tinct_id%22%3A%201752338%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pion_created_at%22%3A%20%222015-08-03%22%2C%22platform%22%3A%20%22web%22%2C%%22%3A%20%%22%7D; t_session=BAh7DUkiD3Nlc3NpbWVfZV9uYW1lBjsARkkiH1BhY2lmaWMgVGltZSAoVVMgJiBDYW5hZGEpBjsAVEkiFXNpZ25pbl9wZXJzb25faWQGOwBGaQMSvRpJIhRsYXN0X2xvZ2luX2RhdGUGOwBGVTogQWN0aXZlU3VwcG9ydDo6VGltZVdpdGhab25lWwhJdToJVGltZQ2T3RzAAABA7QY6CXpvbmVJIghVVEMGOwBUSSIfUGFjaWZpZWRfZGFzaGJvYXJkX21lc3NhZ2UGOwBGVA%3D%3D--6ce6ef4bd6bc1a469164b6740e7571c754b31cca
```

I'd like to use this cookie in a Python Requests request. (I modified the cookie slightly, so that it can't be used by readers for nefarious purposes!).

However, Requests appears to use a [dictionary format for sending cookies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/), and I'm having trouble converting the above string/blob into a dictionary format.

My question is:

- Is there an automated way to convert a string (like the cookie I captured in Fiddler) into a dictionary in Python?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You should be able to use `SimpleCookie` which is available in the standard Python library:

```
from http.cookies import SimpleCookie

rawdata = 'devicePixelRatio=1; ident=exists; __utma=13103r6942.2918; __utmc=13103656942; __utmz=13105942.1.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); mp_3cb27825a6612988r46d00tinct_id%22%3A%201752338%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pion_created_at%22%3A%20%222015-08-03%22%2C%22platform%22%3A%20%22web%22%2C%%22%3A%20%%22%7D; t_session=BAh7DUkiD3Nlc3NpbWVfZV9uYW1lBjsARkkiH1BhY2lmaWMgVGltZSAoVVMgJiBDYW5hZGEpBjsAVEkiFXNpZ25pbl9wZXJzb25faWQGOwBGaQMSvRpJIhRsYXN0X2xvZ2luX2RhdGUGOwBGVTogQWN0aXZlU3VwcG9ydDo6VGltZVdpdGhab25lWwhJdToJVGltZQ2T3RzAAABA7QY6CXpvbmVJIghVVEMGOwBUSSIfUGFjaWZpZWRfZGFzaGJvYXJkX21lc3NhZ2UGOwBGVA%3D%3D--6ce6ef4bd6bc1a469164b6740e7571c754b31cca'
cookie = SimpleCookie()
cookie.load(rawdata)

# Even though SimpleCookie is dictionary-like, it internally uses a Morsel object
# which is incompatible with requests. Manually construct a dictionary instead.
cookies = {k: v.value for k, v in cookie.items()}
```

If you are using Python 2, you will have to import from `Cookie` instead of `http.cookies`.

Docs:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookie.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html

Comment: In the above cookie, what is `mp_3cb27825a6612988r46d00tinct_id%22%3A%201752338%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pion_created_at%22%3A%20%222015-08-03%22%2C%22platform%22%3A%20%22web%22%2C%%22%3A%20%%22%7D; `, why doesn't it follow the key=value format?

Comment: Not sure. I just copy-pasted what the OP provided.

Comment: When you use Cookie module, that part seems dropped, making me wonder about the format of cookie...

Comment: @zyxue My example cookie is probably messed up, as I was randomly deleting characters from it before posting for security reasons.

Comment: this only returns the first cookie for me, because the cookie value contain whitespace like date stamp for example. Or what if the cookie contains also path and domain and HTTPOnly option?

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/92012

Answer (score 4):

Try this function. It supports more cookie attributes like comment, priority, version and Max-Age:

```
def Robotcookie(cookie: str, parent_domain: str):
    items = cookie.split(';')
    SameSite = HttpOnly = Secure = Domain = Path = Expires = Comment = MaxAge = CookieName = CookieValue = Size = Sessionkey = Version = Priority = None
    CookieName = CookieValue = None
    idx = len(items) - 1
    while idx >= 0:
        item = items[idx].strip()
        idx -= 1
        if not item:
            continue
        SameSiteMatched = re.match(r'^SameSite(.*)?', item, re.I)
        HttpOnlyMatched = SameSiteMatched or re.match(r'^HttpOnly(.*)$', item, re.I)
        SecureMatched = HttpOnlyMatched or re.match(r'^Secure(.*)$', item, re.I)
        DomainMatched = SecureMatched or re.match(r'^Domain(.*)?', item, re.I)
        PathMatched = DomainMatched or re.match(r'^Path(.*)?', item, re.I)
        ExpiresMatched = PathMatched or re.match(r'^Expires(.*)?', item, re.I)
        CommentMatched = ExpiresMatched or re.match(r'^Comment(.*)?', item, re.I)
        MaxAgeMatched = ExpiresMatched or re.match(r'^Max-Age=(.*)?', item, re.I)
        VersionMatched = MaxAgeMatched or re.match(r'^Version=(.*)?', item, re.I)
        PriorityMatched = VersionMatched or re.match(r'^priority=(.*)?', item, re.I)
        matched = SameSiteMatched or HttpOnlyMatched or SecureMatched or DomainMatched or PathMatched or ExpiresMatched or CommentMatched or MaxAgeMatched or VersionMatched or PriorityMatched
        if matched:
            val = matched.groups(0)[0].lstrip('=')
            if matched == SameSiteMatched:
                SameSite = val if val.lower() in ['strict', 'lax', 'none'] else None
            elif matched == HttpOnlyMatched:
                HttpOnly = True
            elif matched == SecureMatched:
                Secure = True
            elif matched == DomainMatched:
                Domain = val
            elif matched == PathMatched:
                Path = val
            elif matched == PathMatched:
                Path = val
            elif matched == ExpiresMatched:
                Expires = val
            elif matched == CommentMatched:
                Comment = val
            elif matched == MaxAgeMatched:
                MaxAge = val
            elif matched == VersionMatched:
                Version = val
            elif matched == PriorityMatched:
                Priority = val
        else:
            CookieMatched = re.match(r'^(.[^=]*)=(.*)?', item, re.I)
            if CookieMatched:
                CookieName, CookieValue = CookieMatched.groups(0)

    Sessionkey = True if not Expires else False
    Size = (len(CookieName) if CookieName else 0) + (len(CookieValue) if CookieValue else 0)

    Domain = parent_domain if CookieName and not Domain else Domain
    Path = '/' if CookieName and not Path else Path
    Priority = 'Medium' if CookieName and not Priority else Priority.title() if Priority else 'Medium'

    Cookie = {
        CookieName: CookieValue,
        'Domain': Domain,
        'Path': Path,
        'Expires': Expires,
        'Comment': Comment,
        'MaxAge': MaxAge,
        'SameSite': SameSite,
        'HttpOnly': HttpOnly,
        'Secure': Secure,
        'Size': Size,
        'Sessionkey': Sessionkey,
        'Version': Version,
        'Priority': Priority
    }
    return Cookie if CookieName else None
```

Example code:

```
cookie = 'name=bijaya; comment=Comment1; expires=Mon, 26-Jul-2021 06:34:02 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=none; Max-Age=244114; Version=1.2; priority=high;'
CookieDict = Robotcookie(cookie, parent_domain='google.com')
# Output:
# {'name': 'bijaya', 'Domain': '.google.com', 'Path': '/', 'Expires': None, 'Comment': 'Comment1', 'MaxAge': '244114', 'SameSite': 'none', 'HttpOnly': True, 'Secure': True, 'Size': 179, 'Sessionkey': True, 'Version': '1.2', 'Priority': 'High'}
```

Comment: This old question already contains an accepted answer. Can you explain (by editing your answer) where your answer differs from the other answer? Also know that Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: @7uc1f3r thank you !!. Yes you are right but this function additionally find extra cookie attributes like comment,version,max-age, session key, size

Answer (score 3):

For a plain cookie string (`document.cookies`)

```
cookies = (dict(i.split('=', 1) for i in rawdata.split('; ')))
```

Comment: This doesn't work when there's `=` in cookie values.