# Parse cookie string to array or something else in python

Tags: python, cookies, http-headers

i have many cookie strings that i get from a http response and save in a set. For example like this:

```
cookies = set()
cookies.add("__cfduid=123456789101112131415116; expires=Thu, 27-Aug-20 10:10:10 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly; Secure")
cookies.add("MUID=16151413121110987654321; domain=.bing.com; expires=Mon, 21-Sep-2020 10:10:11 GMT; path=/;, MUIDB=478534957198492834; path=/; httponly; expires=Mon, 21-Sep-2020 10:10:11 GMT")
```

Now i would like to parse that strings to an array or something else to access the data (domain, expires, ...) easier. For example like this:

```
cookie['MUID']['value']
cookie['MUID']['domain']
cookie['MUIDB']['path']
cookie['__cfduid']['Secure']
...
```

But i don't know how i do this. I try it with the `SimpleCookie` from `http.cookies` but i get not the expected result.

Comment: Check this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32281245/2635392

Answer (score 0):

You should create a python dictionary for this.

```
from collections import defaultdict
cookies = defaultdict(str)
list_of_strings = ["__cfduid=123456789101112131415116; expires=Thu, 27-Aug-20 10:10:10 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly; Secure"]# this is your list of strings you want to add
for string in list_of_strings:
    parts = string.split(";")
    for part in parts:
        temp = part.split("=")
        if len(temp) == 2:
            cookies[temp[0]] = temp[1]
```

Comment: Thanks but what is with attributes like`Secure` or `HttpOnly`? And what is with the strings that contains two or more single cookies like `MUID=16151413121110987654321; domain=.bing.com; expires=Mon, 21-Sep-2020 10:10:11 GMT; path=/;, MUIDB=478534957198492834; path=/; httponly; expires=Mon, 21-Sep-2020 10:10:11 GMT`? This contains the cookie `MUID` and `MUIDB`

Comment: did you use above code to run on sample cookies strings? I hope it will cover most of the cases

Comment: If you want to keep `HttpOnly` or `Secure` then you can do this `cookies['HttpOnly'] = 1` and `cookies['Secure']=1`

Comment: Now it try the code above and get an error `key, value = part.split("=") ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! It gives me a [curious output](https://pastebin.com/raw/1S8bQDhB). I would like to access every attribute from a specific cookie (for example the cookie with the name `__cfduid`] like this: `cookies['__cfduid']['domain']` or for example the `path` like this: `cookies['__cfduid']['path']`