# How can i use code to extract session parameter

Tags: python, parsing

I need to extract the session variable from the following API response: "SESSION=XXXXXXXXXXXX; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; Samesite=Lax".
What is the simplest Python code to accomplish this task by parsing the response at the semicolon delimiter?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32281245/75103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse it yourself, e.g.

```
>>> s = 'SESSION=XXXXXXXXXXXX; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; Samesite=Lax'
>>> s.split(';')[0].split('=')[1]
'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

or

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search(r'SESSION=([^;]+)', s)
>>> m.groups(1)
('XXXXXXXXXXXX',)
```

But the best approach would be to use the [http.cookies](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html) module:

```
>>> from http.cookies import SimpleCookie
>>> cookie = SimpleCookie()
>>> cookie.load(s)
>>> cookie['SESSION'].value
'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using *Python3*, you can use *[bracket notation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)* to acquire a substring.
And, the *[str.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)* method to locate the indices of the *=*, and *;*.

```py
string = 'SESSION=XXXXXXXXXXXX; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; Samesite=Lax'
string = string[string.find('=') + 1:string.find(';')]
```

Output

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX
```